# how can we filter a list and show result if any part of the input text match list javascript

Tags: javascript

I have data that would come from api that I am trying to filter. Basically what I want to do is have input text and if any word of my input text is found in the source I want to get the value

```
//example 1 the word jerry is found in the list so it will console.log jerry
findText ='is there a jerry' 

const list = ['jerry', 'reading', 'good']

const results = list.filter(e => e === findText)
console.log(results) // jerry


//example 2. the word reading and everyone is found in the list so console.log reading and good. 
findText ='is reading for everyone' 

const list = ['jerry', 'reading', 'good', everyone]

const results = list.filter(e => e === findText)
console.log(results) // reading
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includeshttps://) here as:

**1)**

```js
const findText = 'is there a jerry';

const list = ['jerry', 'reading', 'good'];

const results = list.filter((e) => findText.includes(e));
console.log(results); // jerry
```

**2)**

```js
// example 2. the word reading and everyone is found in the list so console.log reading and good.
const findText = 'is reading for everyone';

const list = ['jerry', 'reading', 'good', 'everyone'];
const results = list.filter((e) => findText.includes(e));
console.log(results);
```

You can also use Set here as:

```js
const findText = 'is reading for everyone';
const list = ['jerry', 'reading', 'good', 'everyone'];

const findTextSet = new Set(findText.split(' '));
const results = list.filter((word) => findTextSet.has(word));
console.log(results); // ['reading', 'everyone']
```

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript 6 introduced [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
let findText ='is reading for everyone'; 
    
const list = ['jerry', 'reading', 'good', 'everyone'];

const results = list.filter(e => findText.includes(e) );

console.log(results); // ['reading', 'everyone']
```

includes doesn’t have Internet Explorer support, though. In ECMAScript 5 or older environments, use [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), which returns -1 when a substring cannot be found:

```js
let findText ='is reading for everyone'; 
    
const list = ['jerry', 'reading', 'good', 'everyone'];

const results = list.filter(e => findText.indexOf(e) !== -1 );
    
console.log(results); // ['reading', 'everyone']
```